# How could I pass an Android Intent through a "pure Java" layer?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an application that uses [Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

The application uses NFC, and as such at some point I have an Intent that pertains to the NFC mechanism. I need to pass this Intent to a third-party library that requires it.

I receive this Intent by overriding Activity#onNewIntent() in my "view" layer. However, the third-party library that has to consume this Intent is in another structural layer. Those two layers have no knowledge of each other.

Between these layers lies a Java library that has no knowledge of Android, and is the proxy between them. This is where use cases are implemented. This portion cannot be made dependent on Android, because we are starting to implement it in C++.

My question is how could I make my Intent transit through the Java-only library, without resorting to pass it as Object and then down-casting it when consuming it?

A solution I considered was converting the Intent to a Parcel, but I am stuck with the same problem: Parcel is Android-specific.

I would like to avoid a bus mechanism, if possible.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you need to pass the intent itself, not just the data it wraps? Anyway you get just a string or a primitive through NFC, it can be easily passed through pure java, or there is something not allowing this?

Comment: @DeividasStrioga Because A Tag is stored in this Intent, but I guess I could try extracting each of its bit of information then re-construct it. But I cannot find out how to re-construct a Tag object without an existing Parcel object.

Comment: What lib do you use? Do you pass the intent to it?

Comment: @DeividasStrioga Gemalto; it requires an Intent. The documentation indicates the Intent must have the Tag stored as a Parcelable; if I could recreate it from scratch it would work I guess.

Comment: I have just checked, Tag does not have a public constructor. So I see two solutions available. Either it is possible to pass something else than intent to the lib, maybe it has some other methods. If not then maybe it is possible to fork and modify the lib, adding the necessary wrapper. Other option is to rethink your architecture. https://five.agency/android-architecture-part-3-applying-clean-architecture-android/ this example is also clean architecture, but it has one separate module for device related stuff. You might use the lib and create the wrapper there.

Comment: @DeividasStrioga thanks for your help. I cannot fork the library since it is closed-source. I'll look into the article you link to; in the meantime, I will try to pass the Parcel as `byte[]` with [Parcel#marshall()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#marshall()).

Comment: Good luck, please inform on the progress.

Comment: @DeividasStrioga I ended up marshalling the Tag into a byte[] then re-construct it in the other module and it works fine. Thanks again